How to change Push Button color in guizero python library
Spy Name Generator Code (guizero python module/macOS)
This code doesn't change background color of the push button
# Widgets ---------------
title = Text(app, "Push the red button to find out your spy name")
button = PushButton(app, choose_name, text="Tell me!")
button.bg = "red"
button.text_size = 30`

Want to change the push button's color

do you get error message when you run it in console? If you get error then show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image). In question add also information about system, Python and module. Maybe some systems don't allow to change color for buttons.

it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code which we could simply copy and test.

I tested on Linux and I get red background. As I know MacOS may not allow for some changes. And then only idea is to use images (with text) in buttons.
